# Is it possible to create a jQuery function that plays around with the name of the selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a counter for "Number of characters left" in a form:

```
<input type="text" id='username_input'>
<input type="text" id='password_input'>
```

Is it possible to make a function whose parameter will be part of the selector? 
So you can understand my question better, I'll show you an example that I did, and that doesn't work.

What I'm trying to do will seem obvious. This implies I have to standardize all id's. 
I'm aware I could make a maxChar parameter in the function, but I left my mistake `field+'_maxChar'` so that you can tell me why it's not possible.

THanks a lot in advance

```
var username_maxChar=20,password_maxChar=30;

function countLeft(field,minCharacters){
$('#'+field+'_input').keyup(function(){
    var input_length = $('#'+field+'_input').val().length;
    var input_count = field+'_maxChar' - input_length;
    $('#'+field+'_counter').text(input_count);


    }); 
    }

countLeft(username,6);
```

Comment: The `maxlength` attribute is specifically provided for setting max number of characters.  Why not use that instead?  Then it would be part of the `<input>` and could be read directly from the attributes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Indeed, getting the maxlength attribute seems more appropriate. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have defined these with the `var` keyword outside the function scope, they become properties of the `window` object and can be accessed with the `[]` notation:

```
var input_count = window[field + '_maxChar'] - input_length;
```

However, you might consider just using the `maxlength` attribute:

```
<input type="text" id='username_input' maxlength='20'>
<input type="text" id='password_input' maxlength='30'>
```

These are available to jQuery via `.attr()`

```
var input_count = $('#' + field + '_input').attr('maxlength') - input.length;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Yes thanks for your tip on the syntax. I might use the maxlength instead since I was already using it in my own code. Thanks a lot